# Dualshock 4 controller & Steam

Tags: steam

When I connect my Dualshock 4 controller over Bluetooth or via the USB cable to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, the controller is successfully paired and the touch area can be used to move the mouse. However, Inside Steam big picture mode or while playing a game, my controller is not recognized/do nothing.

As far as I know, I should not install any package for this controller as the Kernel now provide support for that. So what am I doing wrong ? Note that I pair the controller before running Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I still don't understand why but I found a way to have it working:

1. Quit Steam
2. Install `ds4drv`: `sudo pip install ds4drv`
3. Pair your controller via Bluetooth by holding both the `share` and `Playstation` button for 3 seconds
4. When it is paired, the touch area on the controller move the mouse.
5. Run the following command: `sudo ds4drv --hidraw`
6. Start Steam & enjoy